# How to get value of each centroids in a k means cluster?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a csv file which looks like below

```
date                       mse                                                  
2018-02-11                 14.34
2018-02-12                 7.24
2018-02-13                 244.5
2018-02-14                 3.5
2018-02-16                 12.67
2018-02-21                 45.66
2018-02-22                 15.33
2018-02-24                 98.44
2018-02-26                 23.55
2018-02-27                 45.12
2018-02-28                 78.44
2018-03-01                 34.11
2018-03-05                 23.33
2018-03-06                 127.45
...                        ...   
...                       ...
```

Now I want to get two clusters so that I know what values lies to which cluster and their mean.

Now it usually needs two parameters or set of values.Since I am just concerned about the `mse` values and a cluster around it, I pass the other parameter as range which is of same size as no of mse values.This is what I did

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df = pd.read_csv("generate_csv/all_data_device.csv", parse_dates=["date"])
df = df[df['mse'].values < 15000]
f1 = df['mse'].values
# generate another list of equal size
f2 = list(range(0, len(f1)))
X = np.array(list(zip(f1, f2)))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)

labels = kmeans.predict(X)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels)
ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='*', c='#050505', s=1000)
plt.title('K Mean Classification (mse < 15000)')
plt.show()
```

This is what I get

[image]

Now I can get centroid coordinates by doing something like this

```
# Centroid coordinates
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroids)
```

But I want the value of each of the centroids.In other words since the centroids represent mean of all the mse values under each cluster, I want this mean value for each of the cluster.How can I do it?

Comment: `kmeans.cluster_centers_.ravel()` - will give you a vector (1D) of centroids coordinates (one coordinate [1D] for each cluster)

Comment: @MaxU I want the mse value of the centroid since centroid stores the mean of all the mse values under that cluster .How can I do that?

Comment: `kmeans.cluster_centers_` / `kmeans.cluster_centers_.ravel()` - gives you exactly that ;-)

Comment: if you need something different - please post your desired data set

Comment: @MaxU ok this is where I was going wrong.Got it!You may post this as an answer and I will accept.